Determining residence for tax treaty benefits
I am trying to determine whether I qualify for tax treaty benefits, specifically in the context of the W8-BEN form. I need to submit this form because I hold US stocks, and therefore am taxed by the US on dividends. I know similar questions have been asked before on here, but they seem to be all concerned with students/research fellows living in the US, which is not my case.
I am a citizen of country A but I currently live, receive income and pay taxes in country B. Country A has a tax treaty with the US, and I would like to know if I qualify as resident of country A solely based on my citizenship.
I guess my question boils down to: is "residence" for eligibility for tax treaty benefits equivalent to "residence for tax purposes"?

If you are a citizen of A, and live/work/earn in B, then where does the US come into things?

I hold US stocks, and I am therefore taxed by the US on the dividends from these stocks.

That info should be edited into the question.

Done. And thanks to littleadv for the clear answer.

this all depends on the specifics involved.

This is a sophisticated question!

No, you do not qualify solely based on your citizenship. Tax treaties are based on tax residency, to avoid issues of double taxation. If you're not a tax resident of country A, and the country has a treaty with the US - that treaty doesn't apply to you. If you were a tax resident of country A, then that treaty would apply, regardless of citizenship.
The only country where citizenship leads to automatic tax residency is the US itself, and its standard tax treaty boilerplates include a clause allowing it to exclude its citizens from almost all of the treaty provisions (the "saving" clause).

cheers L.A. .. .you know what I think there are actually THREE or so countries with that shitty system. I think the Fil, and somewhere obscure ?

scratch that - maybe it's not the phillipines, but there's another 1 or 2 ...

@Fattie there isn't actually. The usual suspect is Eritrea, but it doesn't treat expats as residents. The income tax applied to expats is different than the one applied locally, in that case.

littleadv - thumbs up
